# How can I get ACF repeater sub_field values to conditionally display in table?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin in a WordPress site and attempting to display product specifications inside a table. Some of the products have mandatory fields and some are optional. Hence I am trying to put together some logic to create dynamic tables. If not data is entered in the optional values, I don't want them to appear in table, nor the headers for the table to appear.

I am having trouble putting it together. Can anyone suggest an approach that can work? My code below:

```
if( have_rows('product_details') ): ?>

    <h2>Product Details</h2>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>
                <?php if(get_sub_field('carton_size')): ?>
                    Carton Size
                <?php endif ?>
            </th>
            <th>
                <?php if(get_sub_field('box_quantity')): ?>
                    Box QTY
                <?php endif ?>
            </th>
            <th>
                <?php if(get_sub_field('weight')): ?>
                    Weight
                <?php endif ?>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <?php while ( have_rows('product_details') ) : the_row(); 

            // vars
            $sku = get_sub_field('sku');
            $size = get_sub_field('size');
            $carton_size = get_sub_field('carton_size');
            $box_quantity = get_sub_field('box_quantity');
            $weight = get_sub_field('weight');
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $sku ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $size ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $carton_size ?>
            <td>
                <?php if(get_sub_field('box_quantity')): ?>
                    <?php echo $box_quantity ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php if(get_sub_field('weight')): ?>
                    <?php echo $weight ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that did work for me. Probably not the most elegant but it displays and formats well. Just places a dash in table when value does not exist:

```
<?php
if( have_rows('product_details') ): ?>

    <h3>Product Details</h3>

    <table class="product_spec">
        <tr>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Size (mm)</th>
            <th>Carton Size (mm)</th>
            <th>Box QTY</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
        </tr>

        <?php while ( have_rows('product_details') ) : the_row(); 

            // vars
            $sku = get_sub_field('sku');
            $size = get_sub_field('size');
            $carton_size = get_sub_field('carton_size');
            $box_quantity = get_sub_field('box_quantity');
            $weight = get_sub_field('weight');
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $sku ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $size ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php if($carton_size):
                    echo $carton_size;
                else : ?>
                    -
                <?php endif ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php if($box_quantity):
                    echo $box_quantity;
                else : ?>
                    -
                <?php endif ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php if($weight):
                    echo $weight;
                else : ?>
                    -
                <?php endif ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```